# Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in JavaScript?
like

```
for(){
     for(){
            .
            . 
            n-times
         }
    }
```

Comment: recursion........

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?